# Checkbox to change div color on selection

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to add a simple check off a shopping item on selection, and change the background color. When I click any option, it just chooses the first checkbox and doesn't change the color.

Why is this happening and how to do fix this?

```
(".check").on("change", function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
});

.item.checked{
  background: #CCC;
}

<label for="add_check">
    <div class="item">
       <input type="checkbox" id="add_check" class="check" style="float: left;" />
       <div style="display: inline-block">
           <a href="">Milk</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</label>
```

Full [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BD5v7/5/) to show you what I'm working with. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Fix the obvious syntax error (missing a dollar sign) and it works -> http://jsfiddle.net/BD5v7/6/

Comment: @edeneo thank you for pointing that out. :) But that still doesn't solve why I can't select other options.

Comment: @Modelesq - Did you try adeneo's fiddle? Seems to work fine.

Comment: @j08691 I did. But again, if you try to select other items, it only checks the first. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important** Are you trying to do this with jQuery or css? This is a **pure css** solution.

This is how your selector should look like:

```
.check:checked ~ .content {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BD5v7/11/)

If you are trying to select the entire area then you can do this, (**Important**: The input MUST be before the effected content)

html:

```
<label for="milk">
    <input type="checkbox" id="milk" class="check" style="float: left;" />
    <div class="item">
       <div class="content" style="display: inline-block">
           <a href="">Milk</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</label>
```

css:

```
.check:checked ~ .item {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BD5v7/19/)

**Future help**, run your html through a validator to find obvious errors, [validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: And I'd prefer to do it with css. And I'm trying to add it to the parent class .item.

Comment: Refer to my updated answer, I was a bit confused so I apologize.

Comment: Thank you. Also, any reason why I can't click on other options? If I click the 2nd option label; it selects the first.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/BD5v7/19/. When using Ids, they are unqiue and only to be used once on a page. Since the label was for the same id, only the first one would be effected when the label is clicked.

Comment: No problem, best of luck in your design mate! A valid html page is a happy page. :]